# Using Test::Unit::Autorunner, no method error for "assert_true"

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, selenium, testunit, selenium-webdriver

NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_true' for #

This is the same for all my assertions.  Test runs but fails to assert.

sample test that fails to assert

```
    class Cwy001 < Test::Unit::TestCase
      def testCWY001
        $base_url = "http://foo.foo.com/"
        $patience = 5
        $user = User.new
        nav = Nav.new
        calendar_m_view = Calendar_m_view.new
        $user.loadUser("Selenium Robot10") #Event Scheduler in the Selenium Users group 
        nav.changeWg("Selenium Users Group")
        nav.goToCalendar
        assert_true(calendar_m_view.add(6)) #make sure that This user can add events to the calendar
        $driver.quit
      end
    end
```

All on its own the test runs just fine but once it is run with the autorunner it errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assert_true` was added in a later version of test-unit. Perhaps you have an old version.

Depending on the version of ruby you need an additional

```
gem 'test-unit'
```

Without you don't get the gem, bit the test suite from your ruby installation (minitest?).

Comment: when this is tried it doesn't recognize that the class is a subclass of TestCase.